# list days in the week, given week and year

Tags: jodatime

Using joda-time, is it possible to get the list of dates in a particular week, given only week and year? All the examples that I found, I need to set a date (with day-month-year), only then I can find the list of dates in a given week.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Joda-Time does not have a dedicated class for the combination of year(-of-weekdate) and week-of-year only. So - within the scope of Joda-Time - you must use a workaround like this code which uses the replacement `LocalDate` with a fixed day-of-week (here: Monday as first day of calendar-week as defined in ISO-8601-standard):

```
int year = 2015;
int week = 52;

LocalDate d = new LocalDate();
d = d.weekyear().setCopy(year);
d = d.weekOfWeekyear().setCopy(week);
d = d.withDayOfWeek(DateTimeConstants.MONDAY);

for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    System.out.println(d);
    d = d.plusDays(1);
}
```

Output:

```
//  2015-12-21
//  2015-12-22
//  2015-12-23
//  2015-12-24
//  2015-12-25
//  2015-12-26
//  2015-12-27
```

Finally you can put the gathered dates into an `ArrayList` or what so ever.

Comment: Just to note: Joda-Time has become a little bit old and is now only in maintenance mode, for example, my library [Time4J](https://github.com/MenoData/Time4J) would enable a stream-based solution: `List<PlainDate> dates = CalendarWeek.of(year, week).streamDaily().collect(Collectors.toList());`